# How can I correctly align widgets on Glade?

Tags: application-development, quickly, glade

I have to make three combo boxes become aligned with each other, on the right of my application, which will contain pre-defined responses to questions asked with labels on the left. However, I can not imagine a way to do this with Glade, since it insists on placing all the widgets next to each other. How can I properly align these widgets?

EDIT:

Here's an application mockup:

[image: Application mockup]

And here's what I have with Glade:

[image: User interface in Glade]

My intent is to make the UI in Glade at least similar to mockup UI.

EDIT (2):

There's the app widget tree:

[image: App widget tree]

Comment: You might want to expand your question as to how dynamic your application is - what are you using to output the questions to.  Are you using GtkGrid's for your alignment etc.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a seperate grid for each label/comboboxtext, but use one grid for all of them. Also, set the x-align property of the labels to 0 for nice alignment.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/yqzgXS1Z) is my attempt, just save and open in Glade.

Comment: Is `xalign`, not `x-align`.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest a different kind of approach, Use `Gtk.Box` with horizontal and vertical orientation, and use margin (from the common tab in glade) to adjust the alignment

[image]

An example can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/WY6UE5dj).

This is my output :

[image]